# Can't pull a docker image on Cent OS server, but works fine on local Ubuntu OS

Tags: linux, docker

This command fails on a CentOS server but succeeds on an Ubuntu based laptop:

```
# server, CentOS based
$ docker pull jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest not found

# laptop, Ubuntu based
$ docker pull jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
latest: Pulling from jwilder/nginx-proxy
Digest: sha256:5069d54302a4982681892b11fda72f6735d8f65bda38ffedeceb767fa28e9d14
Status: Image is up to date for jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
docker.io/jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
```

On the CentOS server that can't pull this image I can pull other images just fine.

```
$ docker pull busybox
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
325d69979d33: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:560af6915bfc8d7630e50e212e08242d37b63bd5c1ccf9bd4acccf116e262d5b
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
```

I tried explicitly specifying the platform on the server (where I'm not an admin) and I got this error:

```
$ docker pull --platform linux/amd64 jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
"--platform" is only supported on a Docker daemon with experimental features enabled
```

There is a docker version difference between the systems that I can't immediately fix. The best guess I could get out of GPT4 was that there's a version conflict here. If that seems likely to someone with more experience I'd love to have a second opinion for or against.

The CentOS server is running this docker version:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:20:16 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   9ee9f40
  Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:23:58 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

My laptop is running this version:

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.1
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.4
 Git commit:        6802122
 Built:             Fri May 19 18:06:21 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.1
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.4
  Git commit:       463850e
  Built:            Fri May 19 18:06:21 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: What happens if you attempt the full path, e.g. `docker pull docker.io/jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest`?

Comment: Nice idea, but the same error occurrs.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing the OS with Ubuntu 22.04 and upgrading docker to the latest 24.0.1 version this problem disappeared. I suspect the docker upgrade was the solution, but I can't be certain.